# How to determine what is occupying a COM port

Tags: windows-10, com

The Device Manager image below shows that devices occupy COM ports 4, 5, 6, and 7.  Attempts to move the device from 7 to 13 failed because 13 was allegedly occupied.  Reboot did not resolve this problem.  Why is 13 marked as occupied only in the UI to change the port setting and not the list of devices?

[image: device manager image]

Comment: [Relevant question](http://superuser.com/q/408976/380318) (for Windows 7 but applicable here).